# when using =std=C++98 to compile, #include<iostream> get error

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, mingw

when I use -std=c++98 to compile, the error occur

```
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h:39:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h:37,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:44,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from 2299.cpp:4:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwctype:89:11: error: '::iswblank' has not been declared
   using ::iswblank;
```

my g++ version is g++(GCC) 5.3.0.
I want to know why......

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (a complete program and compilation command which reproduce the error).

Comment: Because I cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/g/Ww9GpX

Comment: #include <iostream>
int main(){
  return 0;
}
just like this

Comment: is it a gcc patched and compiled by Red Hat?

Comment: I download it from mingw, and I don't know anymore infomation...very sorry

Comment: maybe it is, because I find many .a files